# Eclipse: Change the current workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I have two workspace A and B.
I call from B another class that is in Workspace A.
This occures errors, becuase my code is made only to be called from Workspace A.
Is there a way to call something from a special workspace?

My example:

> Resource.Factory.Registry reg = Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE;
>         Map m = reg.getExtensionToFactoryMap();

This code works (is in Workspace A) perfectly when calling from workspace A, but when I call it from Workspace B it contains the wrong error.
I tried it with **this** but something like

> Resource.Factory.Registry reg = this.Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE;

do not work.
Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can do is , [make a jar](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm) of that project containing that class from  workspace A and add in build path of B .

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I do not know if this can work, because I need one String from the Workspace B. When it is a jar file, it is closed forever and cant get that String, isnt it?

Comment: you need one string only ,from workspace B in workspace A , so then , lets say there is one class Factory in Workspace B , where this string is defined , then it if is public , then you can access it by making instance of Factory class , or make it static , so u can access it like Factory.stringvariable

Answer (score 0):

u cannot do that in eclipse .two different workspace file cannot be accessed .